# Adding p-values to ggplot; ggsignif says it can only handle data with groups that are plotted on the x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data as follows, to which I am trying to add p-values:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggsignif)
library(dplyr)
data <- structure(list(treatment = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), New_Compare_Truth = c(57, 
61, 12, 14, 141, 87, 104, 90, 12, 14), total_Hy = c(135, 
168, 9, 15, 103, 83, 238, 251, 9, 15), total = c(285, 305, 60, 
70, 705, 435, 520, 450, 60, 70), ratio = c(47.3684210526316, 
55.0819672131148, 15, 21.4285714285714, 14.6099290780142, 19.0804597701149, 
45.7692307692308, 55.7777777777778, 15, 21.4285714285714), Type = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("A1. Others \nMore \nH", 
"A2. Similar \nNorm", "A3. Others \nLess \nH", "B1. Others \nMore \nH", 
"B2. Similar \nNorm or \nHigher"), class = "factor"), `Sample Selection` = c("Answers pr", 
"Answers pu", "Answers pr", "Answers pu", "Answers pr", 
"Answers pu", "Answers pr", "Answers pu", "Answers pr", 
"Answers pu"), p_value = c(0.0610371842601616, 0.0610371842601616, 
0.346302201593934, 0.346302201593934, 0.0472159407450147, 0.0472159407450147, 
0.0018764377521242, 0.0018764377521242, 0.346302201593934, 0.346302201593934
), x = c(2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 5.5, 5.5, 4.5, 4.5)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

breaks_labels <- structure(list(Type = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 4L), .Label = c("A1. Others \nMore \nH", 
"A2. Similar \nNorm", "A3. Others \nLess \nH", "B1. Others \nMore \nH", 
"B2. Similar \nNorm or \nHigher"), class = "factor"), x = c(2, 
1, 3, 5.5, 4.5)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))

data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = ratio)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = `Sample Selection`), position = position_dodge(preserve = "single"), na.rm = TRUE) + 
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = .9),    # move to center of bars
            aes(label=sprintf("%.02f %%", round(ratio, digits = 1)), group = `Sample Selection`),
            vjust = -1.5,    # nudge above top of bar
            size = 4, 
            na.rm = TRUE) +        
  # geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = .9),    # move to center of bars
  #           aes(label= paste0("(", ifelse(variable == "Crime = 0", `Observation for Crime = 0`, `Observation for Crime = 1`), ")"), group = `Sample Selection`),
  #           vjust = -0.6,    # nudge above top of bar
  #           size = 4, 
  #           na.rm = TRUE) +     
    scale_fill_grey(start = 0.8, end = 0.5) +
    scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .1))) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = breaks_labels$x, labels = breaks_labels$Type) +
    theme_bw(base_size = 15) + 
    xlab("Norm group for corporate Hy") +
    ylab("Percentage Compliant Decisions") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
    geom_signif(annotation=c("p=0.35", "p=0.06", "p=0.05", "p=0.34", "p=0.00"), y_position = c(30, 40, 55 ,75, 90), xmin=c(0.75,1.75,2.75,3.75,4.75),
              xmax=c(1.25,2.25,3.25,4.25,5.25))
```

For some reason, the last line causes the following error:

```
Error in f(...) : 
  Can only handle data with groups that are plotted on the x-axis
```

Since I am just putting in text and not referring to any variable, I don't really understand why this happens. Can anyone help me out? Without the last line it looks like this:

EDIT: Please note that I would like to keep the space between the third and the fourth column (which is apparently also what caused the problem, see Jared's answer).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Edit

Thanks for clarifying your expected outcome. Here is one way to include `geom_signif()` annotations without altering the original plot:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggsignif)
data <- structure(list(treatment = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), New_Compare_Truth = c(57, 
                                                                                          61, 12, 14, 141, 87, 104, 90, 12, 14), total_Hy = c(135, 
                                                                                                                                              168, 9, 15, 103, 83, 238, 251, 9, 15), total = c(285, 305, 60, 
                                                                                                                                                                                               70, 705, 435, 520, 450, 60, 70), ratio = c(47.3684210526316, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          55.0819672131148, 15, 21.4285714285714, 14.6099290780142, 19.0804597701149, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          45.7692307692308, 55.7777777777778, 15, 21.4285714285714), Type = structure(c(2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("A1. Others \nMore \nH", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "A2. Similar \nNorm", "A3. Others \nLess \nH", "B1. Others \nMore \nH", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "B2. Similar \nNorm or \nHigher"), class = "factor"), `Sample Selection` = c("Answers pr", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "Answers pu", "Answers pr", "Answers pu", "Answers pr", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "Answers pu", "Answers pr", "Answers pu", "Answers pr", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "Answers pu"), p_value = c(0.0610371842601616, 0.0610371842601616, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.346302201593934, 0.346302201593934, 0.0472159407450147, 0.0472159407450147, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.0018764377521242, 0.0018764377521242, 0.346302201593934, 0.346302201593934
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     ), x = c(2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 5.5, 5.5, 4.5, 4.5)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    -10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

breaks_labels <- structure(list(Type = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 4L), .Label = c("A1. Others \nMore \nH", 
                                                                                   "A2. Similar \nNorm", "A3. Others \nLess \nH", "B1. Others \nMore \nH", 
                                                                                   "B2. Similar \nNorm or \nHigher"), class = "factor"), x = c(2, 
                                                                                                                                               1, 3, 5.5, 4.5)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("data.table", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                   "data.frame"))
annotation_df <- data.frame(signif = c("p=0.35", "p=0.06", "p=0.05", "p=0.34", "p=0.00"),
                            y_position = c(30, 40, 55 ,75, 90),
                            xmin = c(0.75,1.75,2.75,4.25,5.25),
                            xmax = c(1.25,2.25,3.25,4.75,5.75),
                            group = c(1,2,3,4,5))

data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = ratio, group = `Sample Selection`)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = `Sample Selection`),
           position = position_dodge(preserve = "single"), na.rm = TRUE) + 
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = .9),    # move to center of bars
            aes(label=sprintf("%.02f %%", round(ratio, digits = 1))),
            vjust = -1.5,    # nudge above top of bar
            size = 4, 
            na.rm = TRUE) +
  scale_fill_grey(start = 0.8, end = 0.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .1))) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = breaks_labels$x, labels = breaks_labels$Type) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 15) + 
  xlab("Norm group for corporate Hy") +
  ylab("Percentage Compliant Decisions") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  geom_signif(aes(xmin = xmin,
                  xmax = xmax,
                  y_position = y_position,
                  annotations = signif,
                  group = group),
    data = annotation_df, manual = TRUE)
#> Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: xmin, xmax, y_position, annotations
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

### Previous answer

One potential solution to your problem is to plot "Type" on the x axis instead of "x", e.g.

```
data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Type, y = ratio)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = `Sample Selection`),
           position = position_dodge(preserve = "single"), na.rm = TRUE) + 
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = .9),    # move to center of bars
            aes(label=sprintf("%.02f %%", round(ratio, digits = 1)),
                group = `Sample Selection`),
            vjust = -1.5,
            size = 4, 
            na.rm = TRUE) +
  scale_fill_grey(start = 0.8, end = 0.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .1))) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 15) + 
  xlab("Norm group for corporate Hy") +
  ylab("Percentage Compliant Decisions") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  geom_signif(annotation=c("p=0.35", "p=0.06", "p=0.05", "p=0.34", "p=0.00"),
              y_position = c(30, 40, 55 ,75, 90),
              xmin=c(0.75,1.75,2.75,3.75,4.75),
              xmax=c(1.25,2.25,3.25,4.25,5.25))
```

[image: example_2.png]

Comment: Hi Jared, thank you for your answer. The problem is that now the fourth and fifth bar are no longer separated (see the figure in my post) Is there any way to do both?

Comment: Ohhh! Sorry - that makes way more sense - sorry I misunderstood your expected outcome (even though it was very clear, my bad). You can get the separation + geom_signif if you provide it "manually". I'll update my answer.